# Как передавать данные процедуре oracle

Tags: строки, oracle, int, procedure

у меня есть процедура, которая принимает на вход параметр типа number
начало процедуры выглядит так -
**proc_data(id_row in number)**
.....

в соответствии с id_row у меня разная логика update-ов

я заметила, что если я вызываю процедуру, таким образом
**begin
proc_data('5');
end;**

то есть передаю строку, то oracle принимает это и обрабатывает данные/

так же я могу вызвать процедуру и таким образом, то есть явно передаю integer
**begin
proc_data(5);
end;**

а вот если передаю не число
**begin
proc_data('dsfsd');
end;**
То соответственно ошибка.

Получается oracle неважно передаю я строку или целое число, он потом сам преобразует значение к целому числу и если это у него получается, то он идет далее по процедуре.
Или все же необходимо в точности передавать тот тип данных, который объявлен?

Это мой первый вопрос, если я что-то написала неправильно или непонятно, отпишитесь в комментариях, как мне улучшить вопрос

Comment: Oracle под капотом делает много преобразований типов. Ваша логика правильная. Идет попытка преобразования одного типа данных к другому и если не получается, возникает ошибка(ORA-01722: invalid number ?). Лучше передавать тот тип данных, который объявлен в процедуре

Comment: Да, в oracle есть явные и неявные преобразования типов [implicit and explicit date type conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Type-Comparison-Rules.html#GUID-6DB331B5-0F34-4215-9A20-16AEA9D7FF4B). Но лучше не полагаться на неявное преобразование по возможности, причины указаны так же в документации.